# Proof of Dixon's identity only using Chu-Vandermonde

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For any integers $a,b,c\ge 0$,
one has the well known identity or Dixon's Theorem:
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^k
\left(\begin{array}{c}a+b\\a+k\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}b+c\\b+k\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}c+a\\c+k\end{array}\right)
\ =\ \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!\ b!\ c!}\ .
$$
There are tons of proofs in the literature, but I am wondering if there is one which **only** uses (possibly repeated) applications of the Chu-Vandermonde identity
$$
\sum_{j\ge 0}
\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\j\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}b\\c-j\end{array}\right)
\ =\ 
\left(\begin{array}{c}a+b\\c\end{array}\right)\ .
$$

I should add, for more context, that I found such a proof and was wondering if something of that kind appeared in the literature. I would be very surprised if it didn't. A good example of what I mean by a proof only using Chu-Vandermonde is the derivation of the single index formula for 6j symbols by Racah in appendix B of his 1942 article ["Theory of complex spectra II"](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.62.438).
BTW, appendix A of the same article also contains a proof of the above identity.

---

**Edit (Mar 28, 2019):**

The proof that I found is contained in Section 3 of the paper: ["An algebraic independence result related to a conjecture of Dixmier on binary form invariants"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11147) which is now available. Given that I did not get an answer to this question since it was posted a few months ago, I would tend to think that my proof is new. Again, if you know otherwise, please point me towards the relevant reference.

Comment: I don't know of such a proof in the literature. This question has now been open for some time, and I would be interested to see your proof using only Chu–Vandermonde.

Comment: It's part of a proof or more general identities which I am including in a paper in preparation. I will definitely let you know when the paper is available.

Comment: Is the paper in preparation now available?

Comment: @LSpice: sorry not yet. I have another one to finish first. Will give you heads up by a comment here when ready.

Comment: @MarkWildon: Sorry for the wait and thank you for your patience. The paper containing the said proof is now posted at https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11147

Comment: @LSpice:  Sorry for the wait and thank you for your patience. The paper containing the said proof is now posted. See my previous comment to Mark for the link.